# Added slicer to filter project engineer and it did not update the budget number

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

So I am trying to filter an element called budget by project manager and project engineer. I added a slicer to filter my project engineer and it did not update the budget #, which is a sum. However, when I went into excel and imported data and filter it works. Any idea?

Comment: Does the both data exist in same sheet or two different sheets?

Comment: Did you add relationship with slicer column ? [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9jnm.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9jnm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes Values get updated but DOM will not be updated. Follow the below steps

1.Create a const filter

```
const filter = {
$schema: "http://powerbi.com/product/schema#basic",
target: {
    table: "table_name",
    column: "column_name"
},
operator: "operator",
values: ["values"]
};
```

2.Get the Pages and Active Visuals
const pages = await report.getPages();

```
// Retrieve the active page.
let page = pages.filter(function (page) {
    return page.isActive;
})[0];
const visuals = await page.getVisuals();
```

3.Get the slicer and set Slicer state

```
// Retrieve the target visual. 
let slicer = visuals.filter(function (visual) { 
    return visual.type === "slicer" && visual.name === "4d55baaa5eddde4cdf90"; 
})[0]; 

// Set the slicer state which contains the slicer filters. 
await slicer.setSlicerState({ filters: [filter] }); 
console.log("Date slicer was set.");
```

}

4. If the DOM is not updated, use `updatefilters` so it will make report to render again

   `await pages[0].updateFilters(models.FiltersOperations.Add,[filter]);`

References:

https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-filters
https://learn.microsoft.com/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/control-report-slicers